# Find if a set of points are a mirror images of each other

Tags: algorithm

I was wondering as to what would be best algorithm to this problem? Given a set of points figure out if they form a mirror image along a line parallel to the y axis. For eg. given `(1,3) (3,3) (5,3) (7,3) (0,7) (8,7) (-1,4) (9,4)`, they form a mirror image along the line `x = 4`

```
(1,3) | (7,3)
(3,3) | (5,3)
(0,7) | (8,7)
(-1,4)| (9,4)
```

I was thinking the best way is to put the points in a HashMap with the key as the `y` coordinate and value as the `x` coordinate. Iterate through the key set and make sure that each key has an even number of values and also take their average. The averages of all the should be the same?

Answer (score 3):

I would do it like:

1. Find the leftmost point.
2. Find the rightmost point.
3. Suppose the points form a mirror image. The axis of reflection must be exactly halfway between the leftmost and rightmost points.
4. Iterate through the points. Reflect each one across the possible axis of reflection. If any of the reflected points are not in the point collection, the collection does not form a mirror image with itself. If all the reflected points are in the point collection, the collection does form a mirror image.

Sample Python implementation:

```
def is_reflected(points):
    points = set(points) #sets have more efficient membership testing than lists
    left = min(p[0] for p in points)
    right = max(p[0] for p in points)

    possible_axis = (left + right) / 2.0

    for p in points:
        reflected_x = possible_axis - (p[0] - possible_axis) 
        reflection = (reflected_x, p[1])
        if reflection not in points:
            return False
    return True

points = [(1,3), (3,3), (5,3), (7,3), (0,7), (8,7), (-1,4), (9,4)]
print is_reflected(points)
```

Comment: Removng the *reflection* point from the *points* set after the check will make it so you only iterate over half the points instead of all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Unless a point lying on the mirror line is considered to be a mirror image of itself, there is no mirror line if the number of points is odd.

---

### *To find the mirror line:*

**Method 1:** Iterate through the points and sum their x-values. When done iterating through them, divide the sum by number of points. This is your x of your potential mirror line. Let's call it x<sub>mirror</sub>.

**Method 2:** Find the x<sub>min</sub> and x<sub>max</sub> values from all your points. Average the x<sub>min</sub> and x<sub>max</sub> and this is your potential mirror line.

---

### *To test if the points indeed reflect by the mirror line:*

Starting from the left-most point, for every (x<sub>i</sub>, y<sub>i</sub>):

- if x<sub>i</sub> is equal to x<sub>mirror</sub> then continue,
- else see if ((x<sub>i</sub> + x<sub>mirror</sub>), y<sub>i</sub>) is present in the inputs.

You have to do this for only *n/2* points.